# Extracting data from a div-class or div-id end with content with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

Suppose there is two html page. page1 and page2

page1 contains html like

```
<div class="content">
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

and page2 contains html like

```
<div id="main-content">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

now i wrote a jsoup parser like

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
             Elements links = document.select("div[class~=content$]");

              for (Element heading2 : links) {
                Elements p = heading2.select("p");
                 for (Element ptext : p) {
                    System.out.println(ptext.text());
                             }
                                 }
```

in this code it says if div **class** contains `content` at the end then it parse the data but when page contains `div id="content"` it cant pasre the data..i know ofcourse it cant... my question is there is any way to check whether the `<div>` **id** or **class** contains `content`at the end of div id/class then parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use comma to specify few selectors independent of each other. So you can create one which will search for `<div id="main-content">` and other for `<div class="content">`

```
.select("div[id~=content$], div[class~=content$]");
```